# undefined method `addresses' for #<User:0x007fc955029380>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, rails-activerecord

I am new to Ruby and Rails, trying to fix an error I constantly get. Not sure how to fix it. Please help..

Route.rb

```
namespace :my do
    namespace :account do
      resource  :details, :only => [:show, :update]
      resources :addresses
    end
end
```

AddressesController

```
class My::Account::AddressesController < MyController

  def index
    @addresses = current_user.addresses
  end

  def new
    @address = current_user.addresses.new
  end

....

end
```

Error - undefined method `addresses'

```
NoMethodError in My::Account::AddressesController#index
undefined method `addresses' for #<User:0x007fc955029380>
```

Schema.rb for customer addresses and users

```
  create_table "customer_addresses", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "line_1"
    t.string   "line_2"
    t.string   "line_3"
    t.string   "line_4"
    t.string   "line_5"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "customer_addresses", ["customer_id"], name:         "index_customer_addresses_on_customer_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_reset_token"
    t.datetime "password_reset_token_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    has_secure_password
 ...
end
```

Customer.rb

```
class Customer < User

    has_many :addresses

    def self.register(attributes)
        customer = create!(attributes)
        return customer
    end

    def full_name
        "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end

end
```

Address.rb

```
class Customer::Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer 

  self.table_name = 'customer_addresses'

  default_scope { where(:deleted_at => nil) }

  validates :line_1, :postcode, :phone, :presence => true

end
```

Comment: can you show your address and user models?

Comment: As a side note, why are you using so many namespaces?

Comment: hi @dax added models to the post

Comment: @mus re:namespaces - to keep "my account" out of way from the rest/keep it tidy, is it not a good idea? Also thank you for your answer, but my models have relationships already - added to post above.

Comment: `current_user` is probably a `User`-instance and not a `Customer`-instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `#current_customer` method to your `ApplicationController` that return a `Customer`-instance instead of a `User`-instance:

```
class ApplicationController
  #…
  private
  def current_customer
    current_user && Customer.find_by_id(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

then change your code like this:

```
class My::Account::AddressesController < MyController

  def index
    @addresses = current_customer.addresses
  end

  def new
    @address = current_customer.addresses.new
  end

  #…
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the relationship on both models.

```
class User < ActiveRedord::Base
  has_many :addresses, class_name: 'CustomerAddress', foreign_key: 'customer_id'
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'customer_id'
end
```

Comment: in Rails 4 you can use class: CustomerAddress